# Text as output in the pipe function in R

Tags: r

I have made this code using pipes in R:

```
df %>% group_by(host_is_superhost) %>% summarise(reviews = sum(number_of_reviews))
```

Output:

```
df %>% group_by(host_is_superhost) %>% summarise(reviews = sum(number_of_reviews))
host_is_superhost    reviews
NO                   204655         
SI                   164876
```

As you can see the not "Superhost" (labeled with "NO") have more reviews than the "Superhost". I want to answer the question: Who has more reviews a superhost or a not superhost? Therefore I would like that my output would be something like:

```
The not superhosts have more reviews
```

What do I have to add at the end of the pipe function in order to see the text that I want?

Comment: You could/should add an example dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, next time I will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
host_is_superhost <- c("SI", "NO", "SI", "NO")
number_of_reviews <- c(1, 2, 3, 4)
df <- tibble(host_is_superhost, number_of_reviews)

df %>% 
    group_by(host_is_superhost) %>% 
    summarise(reviews = sum(number_of_reviews)) %>% 
    filter(reviews == max(reviews)) %>% 
    mutate(answer = if_else(host_is_superhost == "NO", "I am a superhost", "I am not"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try:

```
library(dplyr)
#Code
df %>% group_by(host_is_superhost) %>% summarise(reviews = sum(number_of_reviews)) %>%
  filter(reviews==max(reviews))%>% 
  pull(host_is_superhost) %>%
  paste0('The ',.,' superhosts have more reviews')
```